# Show all the JNDI names under ENC (java:comp/env/) in Wildfly

Tags: servlets, wildfly, jndi

### Background

- I am going to define some JMS queues on Wildfly 20.0.1.
- I can list all the defined queue with `/subsystem=naming:jndi-view` in `jboss-cli`.

### Problem

In the result of `/subsystem=naming:jndi-view`, the JNDI names are not based on ENC (java:comp/env/~). I want to know the JNDI names used in a Java application.

### Question

Is there any way to show all the JNDI names under ENC (java:comp/env/~) that available in a web application on a Wildfly server?

Note: the way that available not only for Wildfly but also other Java EE servers are more preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every EJB container that is deployed in an application server has its own personal internal registry called the Enterprise Naming Context (ENC).

Anything registered in the JNDI ENC can be looked up by name under the java:comp/ env context.

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = ctx.list("java:comp/env/");
while (list.hasMore()) {
     System.out.println(list.next().getName());
}
```

Obs.: The JNDI name resolves to a different context depending on where you invoke the lookup. For example, if you invoke jndi.lookup(“java:comp/env”) within the MyEJB, you will get that EJB container’s ENC. If you do the same within another EJB, you will get a different ENC registry specific to that bean.